# avro GenericRecord get nested value in single call

Tags: java, avro

Having an avro schema with nested object like that :

```
{
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"valueLevel1",
         "type":"string"
      },
      {
         "name":"nestedObjectLevel1",
         "type":[
            {
               "type":"record",
               "name":"nestedObjectLevel2",
               "fields":[
                  {
                   "name":"targetStringValue",
                   "type":"string"
                   }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
   "name":"myRecordName",
   "namespace":"com.mycompany",
   "type":"record"
}
```

To get targetStringValue, we have to traverse all nested objects:

```
    GenericRecord nestedObjectLevel1 = (GenericRecord)myGenericRecord.get("nestedObjectLevel1 ");
    GenericRecord nestedObjectLevel2= (GenericRecord)nestedObjectLevel1 .get("nestedObjectLevel2");
    String value = (String )nestedObjectLevel2.get("targetStringValue");
```

For performance reason, It will be nice to get directly the field targetStringValue by something like :

```
myGenericRecord.get("nestedObjectLevel1.nestedObjectLevel2.targetStringValue")
```

How can I do that with Avro GenericRecord ?

PS : I know I can use type safe SpecificRecord but i don't want to do that for some other reason.

Answer (score 1):

> `myGenericRecord.get("nestedObjectLevel1.nestedObjectLevel2.targetStringValue")`

> How can I do that with Avro GenericRecord ?

Unfortunately, that isn't possible.

You could try to convert the Avro object using JSON using `JSONDecoder` class, then using JSONPath to do something very similar with that, though.